# Seg fault on C++ map access

Tags: c++, dictionary

I've come across a strange issue in some code that I'm working on.  Basically what's going on is that whenever I try to get some information from an empty map, the program segfaults.  Here's the relevant code:
(note that struct Pair is a data structure that is defined earlier, and sendMasks is a std::map that is good)

```
std::map<std::string*, struct Pair*>::iterator it;
for(it = sendMasks->begin(); it != sendMasks->end(); it++){ //segfault
   //(some code goes here)
}
```

I know that the pointer to the map is good; I can do

```
it = sendMasks->begin();
it = sendMasks->end();
```

before my loop, and it doesn't segfault at all then.

Now, if I put the following test before the for loop, it will segfault:

```
if( sendMasks->empty() )
```

As will any other attempt to determine if the map is empty.

This issue will only occur if the map is empty.  My only thought on this issue would be that because I am updating sendMasks in a separate thread, that it may not have been updated properly; that however doesn't make any sense because this will only happen if the map is empty, and this code has worked perfectly fine before now.  Any other thoughts on what could be happening?

**EDIT:**
I figured out what the problem was.

At an earlier part in my code, I was making a new char* array and putting that pointer into another array of length 4.  I was then putting a NULL character at the end of my new array, but accidentally only did a subscript off of the first array - which went off the end of the array and overwrote a pointer.  Somehow, this managed to work properly occasionally. (valgrind doesn't detect this problem)

The sequence was something like this:

```
object* = NULL;  //(overwritten memory)
object->method();

//Inside object::method() : 
map->size(); //segfault.  Gets an offset of 0x24 into the object, 
             //which is NULL to begin with.  memory location 0x24 = invalid
```

I wasn't expecting the instance of the object itself to be null, because in Java this method call would fail before it even did that, and in C this would be done quite differently(I don't do much object-oriented programming in C++)

Comment: Two quick things: 1) updating the map in a separate thread could cause many different problems if not done correctly, and 2) are you _sure_ the map is good? begin() and end() could succeed even if the map is not good: that could be a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

If you are accessing a data structure from different threads, you must have some kind of synchronization. You should ensure that your object is not accessed simultaneously from different threads. As well, you should ensure that the changes done by one of the threads are fully visible to other threads.

A [mutex](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes) (or [critical section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686908.aspx) if on Windows) should do the trick: the structure should be *locked* for each access. This ensures the exclusive access to the data structure and makes the needed memory barriers for you.

Welcome to the multithreaded world!

Answer (score 2):

Either:

1. You made a mistake somewhere, and have corrupted your memory. Run your application through *valgrind* to find out where.
2. You are not using *locks* around access to objects that you share between threads. You absolutely must do this.

---

> I know that the pointer to the map is good; I can do
>
> ```
> it = sendMasks->begin();
> it = sendMasks->end();
> ```
>
> before my loop, and it doesn't segfault at all then.

This logic is flawed.

Segmentation faults aren't some consistent, reliable indicator of an error. They are just one **possible** symptom of a *completely unpredictable system*, that comes into being when you have invoked Undefined Behaviour.

> this code has worked perfectly fine before now

The same applies here. It may have been silently "working" for *years*, quietly overwriting bytes in memory that it may or may not have had safe access to.

---

> This issue will only occur if the map is empty.

You just got lucky that, when the map is empty, your bug is evident. Pure chance.